# Backup Mysql database with shell script - bind-address set to localhost

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, backup, synology

I'm using a shell script to backup my databases from a remote server to my Synology NAS. The script is working fine but when I set the Bind Address in de mysql config @ the remote server to 'localhost', the script isn't working anymore. The script needs a SSH verification.

The question: how can I create the SSH connection / credentials in this script?

Underneath the script I use:

```
#! /bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
PAST=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "30 days ago")
BACKUP_DIR="/volume1/dir/dir2/$TIMESTAMP"
PAST_DIR="/volume1/dir/di2/$PAST"
HOST="myip"
MYSQL_USER="username"
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql
MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump


rm -rv $PAST_DIR 

mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR

databases=`$MYSQL -h $HOST --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema)"`

for db in $databases; do
  $MYSQLDUMP --force --opt -h $HOST --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --databases $db | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/$db.sql.gz"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the command by `ssh`. The modified version of your script should do the task.

```
#! /bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
PAST=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "30 days ago")
BACKUP_DIR="/volume1/dir/dir2/$TIMESTAMP"
PAST_DIR="/volume1/dir/di2/$PAST"
HOST="myip"
MYSQL_USER="username"
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql
MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump

SSH_KEY=""
SSH_USER=""
SSH_HOST=""

REMOTE_COMMAND="$MYSQL -h $HOST --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -s -e 'SHOW DATABASES' | grep -v 'information_schema'"
databases=$(ssh -i $SSH_KEY ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST} "$REMOTE_COMMAND")

created=0

for db in $databases; do
  DUMP="$BACKUP_DIR/$db.sql"

  # To save backup on remote machine
  case $created in
    0) REMOTE_COMMAND="rm -rv $PAST_DIR; mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR"; created=1
       ssh -i $SSH_KEY ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST} "$REMOTE_COMMAND" ;;
    *) ;;
  esac

  REMOTE_COMMAND="$MYSQLDUMP --force --opt -h $HOST --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --databases $db | gzip -9 > $DUMP.gz"
  ssh -i $SSH_KEY ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST} "$REMOTE_COMMAND"

  # To save backup on local machine
  # case $created in
  #   0) rm -rv $PAST_DIR; mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR; created=1 ;;
  #   *) ;;
  # esac
  # REMOTE_COMMAND="$MYSQLDUMP --force --opt -h $HOST --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --databases $db"
  # ssh -i $SSH_KEY ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST} "$REMOTE_COMMAND" | gzip -9 > $DUMP.gz

done
```

***NOTE***: you need to set the `SSH_KEY` (if you have ssh key based authentication), `SSH_USER`, `SSH_HOST` variables. Also I provided two solutions in case you want to save the backup on your local machine, from where you started the command. Also note the `-s` flag with the `mysql` command (`SHOW DATABASES` part), which will not print out the colum name (here `Database`).

Comment: Thanks for the extensive example.

I get a error running this (I use the local save option);

Taak: Database Backup myserver.com
Starttijd: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 14:12:15 GMT
Stoptijd: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 14:12:16 GMT
Huidige status: 0
Standaard uitvoer/fout:
Warning: Identity file/xHAYse7U1JuMJb4Kuu+/nGjQ/rYO8M5fPpnWSb6v2muIUxiJyrC/jIvx3K2ctmx8ROm167rNUxGeh0RiuqN+G+oUv1zXSE3SM7YIP5Z2mK9cfkFxKXMAUcM9pD0YvslfkYG+gEwEbC+rMTVI/SUOBZbd8SfDzbnuS2bwmIlk+NTAP not accessible: No such file or directory.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'serverIP' (111)

Comment: Did you specify the full path to your ssh key with the `-i` flag? Also the `HOST` that is used for mysql can be set for localhost since you connect to remote machine with ssh and execute mysql locally on the remote machine. So `SSH_HOST` should be your remote machine ip and `HOST` can be `localhost` (this is used with mysql in our example).

Comment: I entered the key instead of the path. When I use the path I receive a different error;
Warning: Identity file root@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx not accessible: No such file or directory.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /usr/bin/mysql -h xx.xxx.xxx.xxx --user=remote -kwnvs1avqin5 -s -e 'show databases' | grep : Name or service not known

Comment: This issue is more related to [unix & linux stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) now. Could you connect to remote machine like this: `ssh remote_user@remote_server`?

Comment: Yes I can connect with SSH (without entering a password).
When I connect with Sequel Pro I have to enter mySQL username + password + SSH host + username + password
Could it be that in stead of using the key I have to enter the password?

Comment: Then yes, rewrite the commands like this: `ssh ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST} "$REMOTE_COMMAND"`

Comment: I would suggest you to setup an ssh key authentication for your remote machine instead of using password. Also, you just wrote you can connect to the server without password. Why would you need that?

Comment: It's working now (I made a typo). Only problem is that the directory for today is created but there are no database files in the directory. The output for the cronjob does mention all the databases.

Comment: @dna75 Did you used the script after my last edit, in its current status? Also did you commented out everything for the remote part and uncommented for the local part?

Comment: When I run the task on my Synology Nas it reports a list of all databases. But they aren't added to my nas directory. I used your script with the last edits. I also used the local code.

Comment: @dna75 Maybe I was not clear then. I meant local machine as your control machine. So if you run the script from your control machine against your Synology Nas (remote server) then the `To save backup on remote machine` block from the script saves the backup on your Synology Nas, and the `To save backup on local machine` saves the backups on your control machine, from where you launched the script. Verify whether `/volume1/dir/dir2/$TIMESTAMP` folder is created on your control machine with the sql backups in it.

Comment: Thanks for you patience but I can't get this working (save to local or remote).
I'm running the script on my Synology NAS trying to download the databases from my server.

Comment: Is there any error message that you see during the script is running? I tested the script and it is working as expected.

Comment: I don't know what error I had but It's working now. Again thanks for al your patience and the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Designed to run in Synology DSM > Control Panel > Task Scheduler > User-defined script

TODAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
TIME=$(date +"%T")

################################################################
################## Update below values ########################

DB_BACKUP_PATH='/volume2/Backups/Alpine1MySQL/proddata'
MYSQL_HOST='servername.domain.co.nz'
MYSQL_PORT='3306'
MYSQL_USER='backup'
MYSQL_PASSWORD='backuppassword'
DATABASE_NAME='dbname'
BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS=90 ## Number of days to keep local backup copy
MYSQLDUMP=/volume2/@appstore/MariaDB10/usr/local/mariadb10/bin/mysqldump ## Get this file by installing the MariaDB package in Synology package manager (it doesn't need to actually run)

#################################################################

mkdir -p ${DB_BACKUP_PATH}/${TODAY} | echo ${DB_BACKUP_PATH}/${TODAY} "directory created"
echo "Backup started for database: ${DATABASE_NAME}"

$MYSQLDUMP -h ${MYSQL_HOST} \
-P ${MYSQL_PORT} \
-u ${MYSQL_USER} \
-p${MYSQL_PASSWORD} \
${DATABASE_NAME} | zip > ${DB_BACKUP_PATH}/${TODAY}/${DATABASE_NAME}_${TODAY}_${TIME}.sql.zip

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Database backup successfully completed"
else
echo "Error found during backup"
exit 1
fi

##### Remove backups older than {BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS} days #####
echo "Removing backups older than" ${BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS} "days "
DBDELDATE=`date +"%d%b%Y" --date="${BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS} days ago"`

if [ ! -z ${DB_BACKUP_PATH} ]; then
cd ${DB_BACKUP_PATH}
if [ ! -z ${DBDELDATE} ] && [ -d ${DBDELDATE} ]; then
rm -rf ${DBDELDATE}
fi
fi

### End of script ####
```